# Помогите с сортировкой вставкой

Tags: python, сортировка, insert

Захотел попробовать сделать сортировку вставкой,лишь смотря на одну гифку,и пришел к примерно к такому варианту:

а - массив случайных чисел

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    j = i
    x = i - 1
    if a[j] < a[x]:
        while a[j] <= a[x]:
            a[j], a[x] = a[x], a[j]
```

Подскажите,почему выходя из while,он сразу берет следующий i, а не проверяет if, который стоит выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что и if и  while у вас проверяют практически одно и то-же условие. А индексы не изменяются в цикле. 
Сортировка вставкой в принципе выглядит примерно так:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    v = a [i]
    j = i;
    while (a [j-1] > v) and (j > 0):
        a [j] = a [j-1]
        j = j - 1
    a [j] = v
```

А ваш код сильно смахивает на сортировку "пузырьком" :-) Но -  недописанным. Ну, и с отступами у вас - беда.